# Compound operation evaluation in C++

Tags: c++

When I execute the following code

```
#include <iostream>
int & f(int &i)
{
    puts("this is f");
    return ++i;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    printf("%d", f(x) = f(x) + 1);
    return 0;
}
```

I get output as 8. I am unable to understand how that's happening. Can anyone give me a reason for that?

Comment: `f(x)` increments by 1 so, you can say simply `+1`. Now `x=5`... `f(x)=f(x)+1` is equivalent to `x=(5+1)+1` and then `x+=1` so the final value of `x` is 8. Because basically `x=1+(5+1)+1`

Answer (score 2):

Look how this line of code is evaluated:

```
printf("%d",f(x)=f(x)+1);
```

**Step 1:**
Initialization of x 
--> x == 5

**Step 2:** 
First call of f (right side of equals sign)
--> x == 6

**Step 3:**
Adding 1 
--> x == 7

**Step 4:**
Second call of f (left side of equals sign)
--> x == 8

**EDIT(see comment for deeper insight & thx to Matt):**

Comment: In this order, Step 3 does not cause `x == 7`. After Step 3, `x == 6` still, but the rvalue `7` exists as the result of evaluating the right hand side. Step 4 results in `x == 7`. The `++i` increments `x` from `6` to `7`, and the incremented value is then overwritten with the rvalue `7`.

Comment: Coliru uses your order (see the end of my answer for link)

Answer (score 2):

It's unspecified which of the two calls to `f(x)` occurs first; and if the right-hand-side one was called first, it's unspecified whether the prvalue conversion of that occurs before or after the call to the left-hand-side's `f(x)`. But all of those happen before the assignment.

One valid order is:

- lhs f(x)
- rhs f(x)
- rvalue conversion

which results in `i = 7 + 1;`.

Alternatively it could be:

- rhs f(x)
- rvalue conversion
- lhs f(x)

which results in `i = 6 + 1;`

There is no undefined behaviour relating to the `++` operator, because there is a sequence-point before and after each function call.

Refs:
[intro.execution]#15

> Except where noted, evaluations of operands of individual operators and of subexpressions of individual expressions are unsequenced

[expr.ass]#1

> In all cases, the assignment is sequenced after the value computation of the right and left operands, and before the value computation of the assignment expression.

In this quote, "the value computation of the assignment expression" means the value that this expression takes if it's a sub-expression of a larger expression, e.g. `bar = ( foo(x) = foo(x) + 1 );`

---

This code will let you inspect which order your compiler is using. I have inserted `bar` which passes its value through unmodified.

```
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int & f(int idx, int &i)
{
printf("this is f %s\n", idx ? "right" : "left");
return ++i;
}

int bar(int idx, int z) 
{
    printf("bar%d = %d\n", idx, z);
    return z;
}

int main()
{
    int x=5;
    f(0,x)= bar(0, bar(1, f(1,x)) + 1 );
    printf("final = %d\n",x);
    return 0;
}
```

Output for my system:

```
this is f left
this is f right
bar1 = 7
bar0 = 8
final = 8
```

Output [for Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3cdb708323816cf5):

```
this is f right
bar1 = 6
bar0 = 7
this is f left
final = 7
```

Comment: Hard to believe it doesn't have to call the RHS one first in an assignment.

Comment: @EJP it's been that way ever since day 1 of C (and probably even before that). To do an assignment there's two things to be worked out: (a) where to put the value, and (b) which value to put.  C and C++ don't impose any requirement on which order you work out those two things, as long as you do both before actually putting the value in the place!

Comment: It might make more sense to work out (a) first, as then when you are computing the value you can compute it directly in the destination space, instead of having to store the value in temporary storage while you work out where to put it.

Answer (score 1):

You use reference parameter. When you modify the variable x in the f function, you modify too in main function.

```
First x = 5
When you call f first time, x = 6
When you call f second time, x = 7
Finally, 7 + 1 = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Function parameter `i` is a reference to `int x`.
So, `++i` is actually incrementing `x`.

`f(x)` is called twice with initial `x=5` which will make `x` equal to 7.
But 1 is added at `printf`, making final value printed 8.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

int & f(int &i)
{
    puts("this is f");
    return ++i;
}

int main()
{
    int x=5;
    //f(x)=f(x)+1 equals to following
    int& tmp_x = f(x); //x=6
    int tmp = f(x)+1; //x = 7, tmp = 8
    tmp_x = tmp; //x=8
    printf("%d",tmp_x);
    return 0;
}
```